# How can I add a due date to OS X Reminders?

Tags: macos, reminders, icloud

I would like to know if it is possible to add the *due date* checkbox shown in my screenshots to the OS X version of Reminders. I am not looking for the notification option, just the old fashioned due date option.

The due date checkbox is not an option normally. "Test item" was created on the OS X Reminders app.

However if I make one, "Test item 2", on iCloud.com, I have the option to add a due date. This is then changed, through iCloud, on my Mac.

This leads me to believe that maybe a file could be changed on my Mac to enable this option to be turned on by default.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use AppleScript with this one-liner to create an item with the Due Date independent of the Remind Me Date:

```
tell application "Reminders" to show (make new reminder with properties {name:"New reminder", due date:(current date)})
```

Or you can use Automator to create a Service that does the same thing. That way, you can assign a keyboard shortcut to it in System Preferences. See the Services list under System Preferences… Keyboard… Shortcuts… Services.

In Automator, add the New Reminders Item snippet and make sure Due Date is checked. Use menu item File… Save to save the workflow in the default location (~/Library/Services/). The Service should now be visible in the Reminders application, under menu item Reminders… Services….

Comment: This is really great. I'm wondering if I could add a "Get Specified Text" command in front so that the reminder will have the name of the text I have highlighted. I can get the text but can't figure out how to pass it into the apple script

Comment: Use Automator instead. There's a New Reminders item, and you can set a due date in it. Unfortunately, the service will always set the same due date, but you can immediately modify it thereafter, or just choose to "Show the Action when the Workflow Runs", and set it then.

Comment: I used Automator, but my problem was that I shouldn't have included the `Get specified text` action item; I needed this running in Automator, but didn't when running the workflow.

Comment: I think you have to make it as a Service to get the selected text: http://cl.ly/Waiq

Answer (score 1):

Under the OS X Reminders Application you can **Copy and Paste** reminders. Doing so with previously created on iCloud one, will preserve the *Due Date* option.

Comment: While not ideal, this does work well.