# My service fails with error "WorkflowServiceRunner received error running Workflow Service". How to diagnose?

Tags: automator, automation, services, reminders

I'm following the instructions in the [answer to *How can I add a due date to OS X Reminders?*](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/76968/17600) , to set up a Service which creates a Reminder entry with a due date. I used Automator to create a workflow, with the single step "New Reminders Item", and saved this as `/Users/me/Library/Services/New reminder with Due.workflow`.

When I select text, then run this Service from the app's Services menu, an alert box appears, saying:

> The action "New Reminders Item" encountered an error. [Show Workflow] [OK]

The Console shows an error message like:

> 2017-03-18 22:36:10.084 WorkflowServiceRunner[4697]:
>   WorkflowServiceRunner received error running Workflow Service at
>   /Users/me/Library/Services/New reminder with Due.workflow: The action
>   “New Reminders Item” encountered an error.

I was hopeful about finding an AppleScript syntax error induced by Automator, as in SO [answer to *Apple Automator Applescript action giving “could not connect action” error*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15753346/1099571), but my Workflow appears not to contain AppleScript. It appears to be a bundle directory containing files `document.wflow` and `Info.plist`. There was no AppleScript code that I could see.

How do I diagnose this error?  How can I find out what error the WorkflowServiceRunner received?

I am running Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.6.